# System.InvalidOperationException: The constructors '(int)' and '(string)' have the same number of parameters, and can both be used by EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using this class with Entity Framework Core 7.0.7:

```
public class Collaborator : Entity
{
    public Collaborator(int productId)
    {
        ProductId = productId;
    }

    public Collaborator(string userId)
    {
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The constructors '(int)' and '(string)' have the same number of parameters, and can both be used by  Entity Framework. The constructor to be used must be configured in 'OnModelCreating'.'

Do I need to configure the constructor in `OnModelCreating` or can it be solved in another way?

Comment: Depends what you want EF to do, how do you want EF to construct these objects?

Comment: @Charlieface In this case I do not want to use any of the constructors. I want to use a parameterless constructor and then set each property to the value from the database. However I do not want to expose the parameterless constructor to other classes, only EF.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with a private parameterless constructor like this:

```
private Collaborator() 
{ 
}
```